# HTML Forms into PL/SQL

Tags: html, sql, oracle, plsql

I having trouble thinking about the logic on how to move forward with this:
I am trying to create a HTML form on a webpage, and in that form there's going to be 2 input text boxes, and I am trying to add those text to a table in a database. I am doing this in Toad for oracle by the way. I am making procedures which are going to be added into a package. After this table, I assume to make another procedure to check the text boxes and insert what the inputs into the table.
Heres my code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE procedure PCSPRO.form_alfred

AS

BEGIN

htp.p (' 
 <form action="userINPUT" method="POST" NAME="INPUTFORM" >
      ');

 htp.p ('
  <table border="2" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" summary="">   

 <!--  Table -->

 <tr> Register New User </tr>



    <tr> <td>Employee ID: </td> 
         <td><input type="text" name="EmployeeID" value=""/></td></tr>

    <tr> <td>Employee Name: </td> 
         <td><input type="text" name="EmployeeName" value=""/></td></tr>
     ');

end;
```

Comment: Using something designed for web programming, such as asp.net, php, coldfusion, etc would make this a lot easier.

Comment: Are you working in mod_plsql or APEX listener style environment ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand the question but have a look at this very simple example:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE
PROCEDURE formPage
IS
BEGIN
    htp.prn('<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>simple form</title>
</head>
<body>
<form method="POST" action="formProcess">
<table>
<tr><td>First name:</td><td><input type="text" name="firstname"></td></tr>
<tr><td>Last name:</td><td><input type="text" name="lastname"></td></tr>
<tr><td colspan="2"><input type="radio" name="sex" value="male">Male</td></tr>
<tr><td colspan="2"><input type="radio" name="sex" value="female">Female</td></tr>
<tr><td colspan="2"><input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Car">I have a car </td></tr>
<tr><td colspan="2"><input type="submit" value="Submit"></td></tr>
</table>
</form>
</body>
</html>');
END formPage;
/

CREATE OR REPLACE
PROCEDURE formProcess(firstname IN VARCHAR2, lastname IN VARCHAR2, sex IN VARCHAR2, vehicle IN VARCHAR2)
IS
BEGIN
    htp.prn('<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>simple form</title>
</head>
<body>
<table>
<tr><td>First name:</td><td>'||firstname||'</td></tr>
<tr><td>Last name:</td><td>'||lastname||'</td></tr>
<tr><td>Sex:</td><td>'||sex||'</td></tr>
<tr><td>Vehicle:</td><td>'||vehicle||'</td></tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>');
END formProcess;
/
```

Comment: Thank you this is what I needed, i was trying to make a form for the first procedure and the second procedure i wanted a respond page saying that it was a success but i didnt know how to invokce/call the form in the second procedure.

Comment: may I DM you if i have anymore questions?

Comment: @AlfredHuynh I generally prefer to answer questions on stackoverflow so they benefit the community but you can post your question and then just ping me here.